# Cambiar valor de un atributo JSON con laravel

Tags: php, laravel, json, mvc

Tengo la siguiente estructura JSON de una columna llamada 'json' de la tabla 'activos':

```
{
   "activo":[
        {"id":0,"name":"activo","titulo":"Longitud","contenido":"35 CM"}
        {"id":1,"name":"activo","titulo":"Volumen","contenido":"55 CM"}
    ]
}
```

Por medio del controlador de laravel he podido leer los atributos de ésta forma

```
      echo $json->activo[0]->name;
      (me imprime el nombre)
```

¿Cómo puedo editar por ejemplo el titulo del id:1 sin reemplazar o sobrescribir todo el JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes acceder a la propiedad de un JSON [usando sintaxis de flecha](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#updating-json-columns):

```
DB::table('datos')
  ->where('id', 114)
  ->update([
      'activo[1]->titulo' => 'Otro título'
  ]);
```

(imagino que quieres actualizar el elemento 1 del array de un registro en particular, no de toda la tabla)

Comment: Muchas gracias, pude solucionarlo de otra forma, la cual fue utilizar primero el json_decode, de ahí editar el atributo con una sintaxis similar a la que usted me brindó ($json->activo[1]->titulo= "otro titulo") posteriormente utilizar el json_decode y simplemente actualizar la columna de la base de datos.